# Parse JSON data in jQuery and display in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am going to print the response data from `test.php` in JSON format to print it on particular field

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: data,
   success: function(response) {
   var result = $.parseJSON(response);

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#test").click(function(){
          $("#bemail").val(result.email);//when i prints only result than it displays [object object]

      });
   });
   }
});
```

Comment: You need to show the response

Comment: @Param what response are you getting as output?

Comment: jquery is a DOM parser, not a JSON parser.  You can do it w/jQuery, but perhaps XML is better?

Comment: `$(document).ready` inside `success` callback ? I don't think that will ever trigger..

Comment: result.email is a json object . put JSON.stringify to see the data in this object.

Comment: This is I am getting as respose [{"id":"4243","name":"Usain","email":"usain@bolt.com","phone":"7878454545","marks":"45"}] @Santhucool

Comment: It will be `result[0].email` then. As your response is an array..

Answer (score 0):

you are calling document.ready() inside the AJAX success handler which doesn't get invoked since AJAX call doesn't invoke the document loading again, DOM has already loaded and it loads only once in the life cycle of a page session.

This much should do

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: data,
               success: function(response) {
                  var result = JSON.parse(response);
                  $("#bemail").val(result[0].email); //after you explained the JSON response
               }
            });
```

Comment: Even though it would have disturbed `DOM`, `document.ready()` would not trigger.

Comment: @RayonDabre DOM will be disturbed after the textbox value is updated not on success event.

Comment: What are you saying ? What is relation of `document.ready()` and `DOM` manipulations ?

Comment: @RayonDabre "Even though it would have disturbed DOM" this part of comment of yours is what I was referring to. DOM will not be disturbed on success event.

Comment: I never mentions that DOM will be updated after success callback...My point is DOM updating and `document.ready()` are not related.. You are misleading the OP..

Comment: @RayonDabre Agree that DOM updating and document.ready() are not related, But where is the misleading part in my answer?

Comment: `$( document ).ready()` runs only once in the lifecycle of the page no matter how many time you update the `DOM`

Comment: @RayonDabre I know, but where is the misleading part in my answer. I can update if can spot it.

Comment: __calling document.ready() inside the AJAX success handler which doesn't get invoked since AJAX call doesn't disturb the DOM__ It somehow expresses that if it would have disturbed the DOM then `document.ready()` would have invoked which is totally wrong..I suppose..

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks its works and i clear the concept for DOM

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this . You have to put your ajax inside `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: data,
               success: function(response) {
                  var result = JSON.parse(response);
                  $("#bemail").val(result.email);
               }
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally wrong, it should be

```
function displayEmail() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
      var result = $.parseJSON(response);
      //Just Print the Result in Console using console.log(result)
      $("#bemail").val(result.email);
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    displayEmail();
  });
});
```